# Task.Factory.StartNew and synchronization context

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, synchronizationcontext

A simple question. Here is a part of a WinForms app:

```
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MessageBox.Show("Task!"),
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskCreationOptions.None,
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    Debug.WriteLine("Before Exit");
    MessageBox.Show("Exit!");
}
```

Could someone please explain why I see "Task!" first, and then "Exit" when I run this?

And when I see the "Task!" message box, "Before Exit" has been already printed in the debug output.

EDIT: More simple, same effect:

```
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SynchronizationContext.Current.Post((_) => 
        MessageBox.Show("Task!"), null);

    Debug.WriteLine("Before Exit");
    MessageBox.Show("Exit!");
}
```

EDIT: If I replace `MessageBox.Show("Exit!")` with `Form { Text = "Exit!" }.ShowDialog()`, I see "Exit", then "Task", as expected. Why is that?

Comment: I think this proves that Win32 `MessageBox` API (wrapped by .NET `MessageBox.Show`) **first** process all pending messages, and then shows its modal window. This is unlike `Form.ShowDialog` works.

Comment: MessageBox.Show() is another name for Application.DoEvents(), you get all of the mystifying re-entrancy behavior, only the way for a user to screw it up subtracted out.  Apply the *async* keyword to an event that's only fired once and you created the perfect storm, stacking re-entrancy on top of re-entrancy.  It all really does make sense in a twisted way and it is perfectly reproducible, just very hard to reason about.  Recursion is only understandable when you wrote all of the code.  Look at the stack trace to make sense of it.

Comment: @HansPassant, if I replace `MessageBox.Show("Exit!")` with `Form { Text = "Exit!" }.ShowDialog()`, I see "Exit", then "Task", as expected. Why is that?

Comment: Different kind of recursion, look at the call stack.

Comment: @HansPassant, I removed *async* and `Task.Delay` and nothing changed. I don't see any recursion is taking place here, the stack frame confirms that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact details of Win32 message pumping in the .NET framework are undocumented. Note that the Win32 API has historically permitted reentrant behavior.

When your code starts the task, the task scheduler it's using will request the task to execute on the current `SynchronizationContext`. So it ends up calling `SynchronizationContext.Current.Post`, very similar to your second code example.

The `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` works by posting a Win32 message to the message queue; the message type is one defined internally by .NET to mean "execute this code". (These details are undocumented).

When your code proceeds to call `MessageBox.Show`, it runs a nested message loop, and that is why the queued actions are executing. If you removed the `Exit!` message box, then the actions would execute after `Form1_Load` returns to the top-level message loop in `Application.Run`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing what happens is this:

- You start the task with the current synchronization context. This results in a message being posted (asynchronously) to the current thread's message queue, saying "when you process this message, run this code".
- You do a MessageBox.Show. This creates a new window, which results in the sending of messages (synchronously) to the new window as part of its creation cycle.
- A side effect of SendMessage is that it [dispatches messages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/06/08/150929.aspx). <s>So the posted message is now processed synchronously, along with anything else on the message queue.</s>

Therefore, the act of creating the new message-box window is probably what gives the task a chance to execute first. If you instead did a Debug.WriteLine and a Thread.Sleep, you would probably see the opposite: the Sleep would happen first (since you're not pumping messages) and then the Task would run.

**Edit:** Based on the comments, the OP's behavior occurs when calling `ShowMessage`, but not when doing `new Form`. Those both involve sending window-creation messages, so obviously `SendMessage` does *not* synchronously process all the messages that were already on the queue. (The post I linked explains that SendMessages does dispatch *sent* messages, but doesn't specifically say that it dispatches messages *already on the queue* -- I just assumed the latter, obviously incorrectly.)

I think I was on the right track -- something about the `MessageBox.Show` call is causing the message to get handled before the dialog is displayed, in a way different from what happens with `new Form().ShowDialog()` -- but I wasn't correct about the specific mechanic involved. Anyone else, feel free to research this and come up with a more accurate answer.

Comment: Are you sure about this: *This creates a new window, which results in the sending of messages (synchronously) to the new window as part of its creation cycle.* I thought that MessageBox runs a message loop similar to `Application.Run`, that is, `GetMessage/DispatchMessage` message loop.

Comment: @avo only modal dialogs are run with their own message pumps. This is so that they can be shown from the ui thread and block execution but still received input.

Comment: I think you're right. I've changed new `MessageBox.Show("Exit")` to new `Form { Text = "Exit!" }.ShowDialog()`, and it works as expected, i.e. "Exit!" first. I think `MessageBox.Show` first pumps all messages, and then shows the message box.

Comment: I really expected `MessageBox.Show` to behave like `Form.ShowDialog`, but it does not, obviously.

Comment: @avo this overload does http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cked7698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Okay, well, if `ShowMessage` yields to the task, but `new Form` does not, then my explanation isn't exactly correct, and it's more likely a side effect of something in `ShowMessage`'s modal message loop that's a bit different from `Form.ShowDialog`'s behavior. Someone else can feel free to research this further and post a better answer than mine!

Comment: @Gusdor, it doesn't. Try my code, call it like `MessageBox.Show(this, "Exit!")`. You'll see "Task", then "Exit". Replace `MesasgeBox.Show` with `Form { Text = "Exit!" }.ShowDialog()`, and you'll see "Exit", then "Task".

Comment: @JoeWhite, I see the point. I hope you don't mind if I un-accept your answer for now.

Comment: @avo, absolutely. I had the general gist of it, but obviously my interpretation of Raymond's post isn't quite right. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: @avo What I was trying to say is that `MessageBox` is *not* a .NET `Form`. It's `Show` works differently than `ShowDialog` on `Form` - `MessageBox`'s message loop is in `user32.dll`, not in .NET code. Both pump messages, but you can actually look at the sources of .NET modal forms to see what they do, which can't be said about `MessageBox`, which is part of windows, not .NET. It's still very hard to read, but as far as I can tell, the `Form` version doesn't get the message to invoke the task, so it's only processed after the dialog is shown. Maybe Form doesn't use WM_SHOW?

Comment: @JoeWhite, your answer is great, beside there's no `SendMessage` involved. I think the OP's question simply proves that Win32 `MessageBox` API **first** process all pending messages, and then shows its modal window. This is unlike `Form.ShowDialog` works.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's lay down the facts.

- `MessageBox.Show` creates its own message pump. This uses the current `ThreadContext`, which I assume will be the same as the UI thread in your case - in other words, your application is frozen. `Show` is modal, despite what the name might suggest.
- `MessageBox` is *not* a `Form` - it's created by `user32.dll` and that's also where its message pump is.
- Your method of creating the task will ultimately result in pushing the task to `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`. The queue seems to be maintained per-thread (it's thread-static). Things get complicated when you ask when the task gets actually executed, because now we're dealing with asynchronous callbacks from the outside of .NET. **EDIT**: I was wrong. The fact is that the current synchronization context is a derived class, `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`, which actually does put the work item in the invoke queue, which is tied to windows messaging.
- Everything happens on one thread, as simple as that.
- The task is executed after the debug output. It has nothing to do with the `MessageBox.Show` inside the task.

If I add another `await` after the debug output (`await Task.Delay(1000);`), a fun thing happens - "Task!" is shown, followed by "Exit!" a second later. Two message boxes at once?! What witchcraft is responsible for this?!

It's obvious that the "Exit!" is a modal of the "Task!" form, not our parent. In other words, the second message box somehow got to run "in the context" of the first message box.

This is related to what I was talking about in my original answer. The modal box *steals* the thread it's running on, and handles the message pumping. When the second `await` executes, it runs on our "Task!" form, not the (blocked) parent form.

If we use `Thread.Sleep(1000);` instead of the `await`, this behaviour is lost. However, the `Thread.Sleep` does run before the "Task!" message box, as evidenced by the fact that  as soon as we close the "Task!" form, "Exit!" appears immediately, rather than waiting for a second, while "Task!" has the delay.

The forms rely on windows messaging. Modal forms "steal" the handle of their owner, and process those messages. It is only after the message box closes that a WM is sent to the parent (a simple "set focus" message).

However, `await` in our scenario works on the UI thread, but outside of the message loop. So when we awaited after the first dialog was shown, the code *after* the await executed as if it was run inside the first dialog - the owner of the MessageBox is determined before creating the underlying native message box (it's not a .NET Form!), so it gets the current active window - in our awaited case, that's the "Task!" form. Mystery solved.

The mystery that remains is why the task is run somewhere between the `MessageBox.Show("Exit!");` call and the message box actually stealing the message loop.

This brings us to the grand finale:

We create our little task. However, it has a windows forms synchronization context, so instead of doing anything, it simply adds the task to the queue on the form. This is on top of the queue, so it will be executed as soon as we relieve control of the UI thread.

If we await before showing the "Exit!" dialog, all is clear - the "Task!" is shown first, and at some point (because it's not passed through the messaging queue), the "Exit!" shows as its child.

If we don't await, the `MessageBox.Show("Exit!");` will enter a modal message loop (we can tell thanks to the `Application.EnterThreadModal` event). Then, the WinAPI (user32.dll) `MessageBox` method is called, which immediately pumps. This reads the queued WM related to our queued `Invoke` call - the "Task!"'s task. It gets invoked immediately, and effectively blocks the original Message.Show call, because that one can't process its own messages.

All in all, another good reason not to complicate things on the UI thread. As it seems, be especially vary of `MessageBox.Show`, because it does a lot more than meets the eye.

In reality, you would run your task outside of the UI thread, and only the continuation that needed access to UI would be in the UI thread. Still, it's very interesting how `MessageBox` hijacks what happens - this could backfire spectacularly if your background task gets stuck invoking something on the UI thread, which is effectively taken over by the message box; there goes your asynchronicity :))

Comment: *Your method of creating the task will ultimately result in pushing the task to `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`*. This is **wrong**, there's no other threads here, only the UI thread. You overlooked `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`. Refer to @StephenCleary's answer, which actually explains what's going on.

Comment: @Noseratio Actually, I just overlooked that the synchronization context is a `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`. This finally explains the mystery in its entirety, since that's how the message gets to the windows message queue. I'll remove all references to the `ThreadPool`, since that was obviously a wrong turn and ultimately a dead end. The fact that I wasn't confused enough is a huge failure for me as a rationalist :) I do know that there's no other thread involved. I just didn't realize how bad it was that `ThreadPool` would have anything to do with that situation. Mea culpa.